# Using Template Haskell’s reifyRoles with poly-kinded datatypes?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I would like to find out information about the roles of a type constructor’s type parameters at compile-time. Fortunately, Template Haskell provides such a function, [`reifyRoles`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:reifyRoles). However, it gives me odd results when I use it on poly-kinded types:

```
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/alexis/.ghci
ghci> :set -XTemplateHaskell -XDeriveLift -XStandaloneDeriving
ghci> import Data.Proxy
ghci> import Language.Haskell.TH
ghci> import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
ghci> deriving instance Lift Role
ghci> $(lift =<< reifyRoles ''Proxy)
[NominalR,PhantomR]
```

Oddly, even though `Proxy` only has a single type parameter, `reifyRoles` produces a list with *two* elements. This makes it difficult to figure out which role corresponds to `Proxy`’s single type parameter.

This doesn’t happen for mono-kinded types:

```
ghci> data Foo a = Foo
ghci> $(lift =<< reifyRoles ''Foo)
[PhantomR]
```

It isn’t clear from the documentation what `reifyRoles` actually does here. I have two related questions:

1. If I only care about the roles for type parameters, and I don’t care about the kinds, can I assume that the types’ roles will be the *last* ones in the list? If not, how can I properly select the correct roles for an arbitrary type’s type parameters?
2. What does a role even mean in the context of kinds? Why is the kind of `Proxy`’s type parameter given the `nominal` role?

Comment: Interesting! For anyone else who didn't immediately get what is happening: I think GHC sees `forall k x. Proxy :: (x :: k) -> *` compared to `forall x. Proxy :: (x :: *) -> *` otherwise. In the first case, `reifyRoles` returns the role of the kind variable as well as the type variable.

Comment: Regarding 1, I think that you are correct. Kind variables come before type variables. Regarding 2, the note at [`[TyCon Role signatures]`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/cca2d6b78f97bfb79bef4dc3f75d6c4d15b94680/compiler/types/TyCon.hs#L348-L349) says that all kind arguments have `nominal` role.